# Using multiple loc()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to use multiple loc() on the below table but unfortunately the code is giving me an error stating:

**ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

my df is the following:

```
REFERENCE     PERIOD      QTY      PRICE
abc123        Jan-20       20       21.2
abc123        Feb-20      -40       22.3
abc123        Mar-20       20       22.9
cde456        Aug-20      -10       18.7
cde456        Sep-20       20       19.4
cde456        Jan-20      -10       19.93
```

The code giving me an error should ideally return a subset of the table:

```
dfa = df.loc[df['PERIOD'].str.contains(pat='JAN')] and df.loc[df['REFERENCE'].str.contains(pat='abc')]
```

Any ideas how what im doing wrong to use 2 .loc functions in the same string?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try single `loc` with boolean operator:

```
df.loc[df['PERIOD'].str.contains('JAN') & 
       df['REFERENCE'].str.contains('A')]
```

Comment: Interesting, last I remember conditions needed to enclosed in parenthesis. Seems to work without them now.

Answer (score 0):

You can give two conditions by separating them with `&`. Therefore, you don't need to use two `.loc`.

**With `.loc`**

```
df.loc[(df['PERIOD'].str.contains('Jan')) & (df['REFERENCE'].str.contains('abc'))]
```

Or

**Without `.loc`**

```
df[(df['PERIOD'].str.contains('Jan')) & (df['REFERENCE'].str.contains('abc'))]
```

Output:

```
   REFERENCE  PERIOD  QTY  PRICE
0    abc123  Jan-20   20   21.2
```